# Finite order of all element in a group G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I tried to prove the following, but I could not do it. Please help me.
If $G$ is an infinite group such that, whenever $J < H < G$ and $J$ is not isomorphic to $H$, then every element of $G$ has finite order.

Comment: J is proper subgroup of H and H is a subgroup of G and J is not isomorphic to H then every element of G has finite order

Comment: I've just complete my question

Comment: The wording is still not perfect.  Note that you can edit your Question after posting it.  The `edit` link appears just under the tags for the Question.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose there is an element $a\in G$ of infinite order. Compare $\langle a\rangle$ to $\langle a^2\rangle$.

Comment: I'm not sure how the hypothesis "$J$ is not isomorphic to $H$" is being used in the Question, but in your setup, surely $\langle a \rangle$ and $\langle a^2 \rangle$ are isomorphic.

Comment: @hardmath this solves the problem. If there is an element $a$ of infinite order, then $G$ contains isomorphic subgroups $J<H$.

Comment: @hardmath I'm proving the contrapositive of what I believe the OP is asking, namely "if for any $J,H$ such that $J\lneq H<G$, $J$ are not isomorphic to $H$, then every element of $G$ had finite order".

Comment: It's a good answer to that question!

Comment: Thanks alot but could you explain the proof more

Comment: @Marroo The two groups mentioned in my answer are certainly not _equal_ (one contains $a$ while the other does not) but they are both isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$, as is any infinite cyclic group. That means I have proven "There is an element in $G$ of infinite order $\implies$ there are two subgroups in $G$, one a _proper_ subgroup of the other, that are isomorphic". This is the contrapositive of the statement that you want to prove, and it is therefore equivalent.